# Namenode , datanode not apperaing when "jps" is used when installing Hadoop

Tags: hadoop, hdfs

I am trying to install hadoop in my macbook air m1 , but when i type jps its not showing all the nodes, i will just send the screenshot of all

The below code is what i get when i run `hdfs namenode -format` - Not fully uploaded cause max 30000 characters

```
 NameNodeRetryCache
2022-11-11 19:33:22,044 INFO util.GSet: VM type       = 64-bit
2022-11-11 19:33:22,044 INFO util.GSet: 0.029999999329447746% max memory 1.8 GB = 559.3 KB
2022-11-11 19:33:22,044 INFO util.GSet: capacity      = 2^16 = 65536 entries
Re-format filesystem in Storage Directory root= /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name; location= null ? (Y or N)
```

I dont know which i should press Y/N , but i tried both and its not working

i will show now when i press Y  and N respectively

```
2022-11-11 19:38:13,905 INFO namenode.FSImage: Allocated new BlockPoolId: BP-409547403-127.0.0.1-1668175693876
 2022-11-11 19:38:13,907 INFO common.Storage: Will remove files: [/tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/fsimage_0000000000000000000, /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/VERSION, /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/fsimage_0000000000000000000.md5, /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/seen_txid]
2022-11-11 19:38:13,938 INFO common.Storage: Storage directory /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name has been successfully formatted.
2022-11-11 19:38:13,981 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Saving image file /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 using no compression
2022-11-11 19:38:14,067 INFO namenode.FSImageFormatProtobuf: Image file /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name/current/fsimage.ckpt_0000000000000000000 of size 402 bytes saved in 0 seconds .
2022-11-11 19:38:14,075 INFO namenode.NNStorageRetentionManager: Going to retain 1 images with txid >= 0
2022-11-11 19:38:14,093 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for active state
2022-11-11 19:38:14,093 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for standby state
2022-11-11 19:38:14,097 INFO namenode.FSImage: FSImageSaver clean checkpoint: txid=0 when meet shutdown.
2022-11-11 19:38:14,097 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Vigneshs-MacBook-Air.local/127.0.0.1
```

And N

```
Format aborted in Storage Directory root= /tmp/hadoop-vignesh/dfs/name; location= null
2022-11-11 19:41:56,728 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for active state
2022-11-11 19:41:56,729 INFO namenode.FSNamesystem: Stopping services started for standby state
2022-11-11 19:41:56,737 INFO util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: ExitException
2022-11-11 19:41:56,746 INFO namenode.NameNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG: 
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down NameNode at Vigneshs-MacBook-Air.local/127.0.0.1
```

when i press "start-all.sh " i get

```
WARNING: Attempting to start all Apache Hadoop daemons as vignesh in 10 seconds.
WARNING: This is not a recommended production deployment configuration.
WARNING: Use CTRL-C to abort.
Starting namenodes on [Vigneshs-MacBook-Air.local]
Starting datanodes
Starting secondary namenodes [Vigneshs-MacBook-Air.local]
2022-11-11 19:44:45,167 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
Starting resourcemanager
Starting nodemanagers
```

when "jps"

```
43457 Jps
43284 ResourceManager
43386 NodeManager
```

I tried to install hadoop and I expect localhoest:9870 to work

Answer (score 0):

> but i tried both and its not working

Both work as expected. You press Y - it says `has been successfully formatted.`; you press N - `Format aborted`.

Don't use `start-all`. That's deprecated. You can use `start-dfs`, but it'll probably have the same behaviour. In either case, you must find the namenode daemon log file and open it to find your real error about why the process isn't starting.

You may run into other issues running Hadoop on ARM later on, however